# Aligning data on the stack (C++)

Tags: c++, alignment

This question is specific to the MSVC compiler (specifically 2008), but I'm interested in non-compiler specific answers too.

I'm trying to figure out how to align a char buffer on the stack, based on the alignment of some arbitrary type. Ideally the code would read:

```
__declspec( align( __alignof(MyType) ) ) char buffer[16*sizeof(MyType)];
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work

> error C2059: syntax error :
>   '__builtin_alignof'

The compiler just doesn't like the nested statements.

My only other idea is to do this:

```
char buffer[16*sizeof(MyType)+__alignof(MyType)-1];
char * alignedBuffer = (char*)((((unsigned long)buffer) + __alignof(MyType)-1)&~(__alignof(MyType)-1));
```

Does anyone know of a nicer way? It seems like the declspec thing should work, do I just have the syntax wrong or something?

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: `...the __alignof [struct] is the alignment requirement of the largest element in the structure.` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45t0s5f4(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: If you are trying to save space and compress your data why not just align(1)?

Comment: It's not really about saving space, it's more about allocating space on the stack for an arbitrary type, and respecting that type's alignment requirements. The second block of code does just that, I was just wondering if (as is often the case) there was a nicer way to do it.

Comment: er, why don't you just allocate the object on the stack the normal way? The compiler will align it for you then.

Comment: @jalf That would mean the type's constructor would be called once for each element in the buffer. This is what I'm trying to avoid :)

Comment: Oh, gotcha. (you might want to edit that information into the question itself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Check Robert Knight's answer! Uses C++11 but is much cleaner than this...

---

**Original Answer**

How about this nasty hack:

```
namespace priv {

#define PRIVATE_STATICMEM(_A_) \
    template <size_t size> \
    struct StaticMem<size,_A_> { \
      __declspec(align(_A_)) char data[size]; \
      void *operator new(size_t parSize) { \
        return _aligned_malloc(parSize,_A_); \
      } \
      void operator delete(void *ptr) { \
        return _aligned_free(ptr); \
      } \
    };

    template <size_t size, size_t align> struct StaticMem {};
    template <size_t size> struct StaticMem<size,1> {char data[size];};

    PRIVATE_STATICMEM(2)
    PRIVATE_STATICMEM(4)
    PRIVATE_STATICMEM(8)
    PRIVATE_STATICMEM(16)
    PRIVATE_STATICMEM(32)
    PRIVATE_STATICMEM(64)
    PRIVATE_STATICMEM(128)
    PRIVATE_STATICMEM(256)
    PRIVATE_STATICMEM(512)
    PRIVATE_STATICMEM(1024)
    PRIVATE_STATICMEM(2048)
    PRIVATE_STATICMEM(4096)
    PRIVATE_STATICMEM(8192)

}

template <typename T, size_t size> struct StaticMem : public priv::StaticMem<sizeof(T)*size,__alignof(T)> {
    T *unhack() {return (T*)this;}
    T &unhack(size_t idx) {return *(T*)(data+idx*sizeof(T));}
    const T &unhack() const {return *(const T*)this;}
    const T &unhack(size_t idx) const {return *(const T*)(data+idx*sizeof(T));}
    StaticMem() {}
    StaticMem(const T &init) {unhack()=init;}
};
```

Looks scary, but you need all that only once (preferably in some well hidden header file :) ). Then you can use it in the following way:

```
StaticMem<T,N> array; //allocate an uninitialized array of size N for type T
array.data //this is a raw char array
array.unhack() //this is a reference to first T object in the array
array.unhack(5) //reference to 5th T object in the array
```

`StaticMem<T,N> array;` can appear in the code, but also as a member of some bigger class (that's how I use this hack) and should also behave correctly when allocated on the heap.

**Bug fix:**

Line 6 of the example: `char data[_A_]` corrected into `char data[size]`

Comment: This is a really interesting answer, thanks :) I never thought of manually partially specialising the template for each possible alignment value. The one thing I don't quite understand is why you've had to define your own new/delete operators? My first thought is that its so that the data is properly aligned when allocated on the heap, but wouldn't the standard new do that for you anyway (as you have the __declspec(align(_A_)) in there) ?

Comment: I don't know what standard says about the `new` operator, but tests I made in my Visual Studio 2008 seem to indicate that the data is not necessairly aligned. (I just redid the test a moment ago to confirm)

Comment: yes, all standard mallocs I know of align around 16. fixed, hardcoded. there are some extensions though. cf `_aligned_malloc`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `std::aligned_storage` together with `std::alignment_of` as an alternative.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, int N>
struct AlignedStorage
{
    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T) * N, std::alignment_of<T>::value>::type data;
};

AlignedStorage<int, 16> myValue;
```

This is supported by MSVC 2008 and up.  If you need portability to other non-C++11 compilers you can use `std::tr1::aligned_storage` and `std::tr1::alignment_of` and the `<tr1/type_traits>` header.

In the above code, `AlignedStorage<T>::data` will be a POD type (a char[] array in MSVC and GCC) of a suitable alignment for T and size T*N.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure `MyType` is a valid integer power?

```
__declspec( align( # ) ) declarator
```

> # is the alignment value. Valid entries are integer powers of two from
>   1 to 8192 (bytes), such as 2, 4, 8,
>   16, 32, or 64. declarator is the data
>   that you are declaring as aligned.

-[align (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx)

Comment: In my test case, it is. In the general case it doesn't have to be: 
`__alignof( char )` will return 1.  I guess thats a good enough reason for my first method not to work.

Comment: @JBeFat: `1` is an integer power of `2`... it's 2**0.

Answer (score 1):

How about alloca()? (Or, more specifically, for MSVC2008, [_malloca()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5471dc8s%28VS.90%29.aspx))?

> Allocates memory on the stack. This is a version of _alloca with security enhancements as described in Security Enhancements in the CRT.

Alignment behaviour is not standardised across compilers, but for this one ...

> The _malloca routine returns a void pointer to the allocated space, which is guaranteed to be suitably aligned for storage of any type of object.

Comment: Wow, cool. That's what I'm looking for. The only thing I don't understand is how it can guarantee the space will be suitably aligned for storage of _any_ type of object. I tested _malloca and all it seems to do is return pointers that are 16byte aligned. What if I have a struct that is __dllspec( align( 128 ) ) ? Perhaps there's something I don't quite understand about alignment requirements?

Comment: I think "suitably aligned" means that it's sufficient for correct execution. If you need to align more coarsely than that, for optimisation reasons say, then I guess alloca() won't help you.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem.
You can mash up a macro (*oh horrors*) that combines `align` and `__alignof` in a safe way:

```
// `align` und `__alignof` cannot be combined - hence this workaround where you also have to specify the alignment manually (but checked)
#define ALIGN_FOR_TYPE( TypeName, TypeAlignment )                           \
    const size_t ALIGN_FOR_TYPE_alignOf##TypeName = __alignof(TypeName);    \
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(ALIGN_FOR_TYPE_alignOf##TypeName == TypeAlignment); \
    __declspec( align( TypeAlignment ) )                                    \
/**/

ALIGN_FOR_TYPE(MyStructType, 4) char StructBuffer[sizeof(MyStructType)];
```

Comment: How does that answer the question?   IIUC, the OP wanted exactly to avoid explicitly stating his type alignment.

Comment: @Ofek - it solves the problem in that you'll get a compiler error if you specify the wrong alignment. For a one off solution it seems a tad simpler than the other hacks, and it's still safe, though obviously may need touching the code if the alignment changes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to perform any additional "hacks" if you want to declare aligned data on the stack. The compiler will take care of that.

If you want it to be a char array afterwards, simply cast it to `char*`

Try the following test example to confirm:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct UnalignedX {
    int x;
};

__declspec(align(128)) struct AlignedX {
    int x;
};

int main() {
    UnalignedX arr[5];
    AlignedX aarr[5];
    printf("UnalignedX: %x %x\n",arr,arr+1);
    printf("AlignedX: %x %x\n",aarr,aarr+1);
    char *final=(char*)aarr; //this becomes the char array that you asked for
    return 0;
};
```

On my computer I got the output:

```
UnalignedX: 14fe68 14fe6c
AlignedX: 14fb80 14fc00
```

You have to be careful with alignment when allocating data on the heap (either by `malloc` or `new`)

`__declspec( align( N ))` expects N to be a *literal*. It has to be a number, and not a function call.

Comment: It's more that I want to declare the data as a char, and cast it afterwards. I basically want to construct an array of a particular type on the stack, without their constructors being called. In principle this is as easy as casting the char buffer, but I'd really like the alloc on the stack to respect the alignment requirements of the type the buffer will be used for.